# Sending message sequence to Twilio

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Hello , I want to send a set of messages to Twilio API with some parameters that make sure that they are concatenated and sent a one sms .

I've heard of some **SegmentNum** to use but with no documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

No need, Twilio handles the concatenation for you.

[Does Twilio support concatenated SMS messages or messages over 160 characters?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181508-Does-Twilio-support-concatenated-SMS-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters-)

"When sending concatenated SMS, Twilio will auto-segment long messages with a special header, which mobile carriers can use to reassemble the segments on the destination handset. Thus, concatenated SMS can appear as one single message on the receiving device."